# Show last uploaded file details on redirected page - Django

Tags: python, django

folks. In my application user uploads his/her document on `upload_document` page, submits the form and he/she should see details (for example, document name, document author and etc.) on redirected `result` page. Now I don't know where should I get document itself from `POST` request. Or I'm entirely in wrong way. Here are my codes.

`views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def upload_document(request):
    context = {}
    form = UploadDocumentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadDocumentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('result')
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'upload_document.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def result(request):
    # Don't know what to do here.
    return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class OriginalDocument(models.Model):
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/original_document', blank=False)
    document_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    teacher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    checked_by = CurrentUserField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.document_title
```

As a user, I'm using django's built-in user.

Comment: Someone deleted following comment. But there was an answer. What did you do ?!

Comment: You can do this on your result page by this simple query  `YourModel.objects.filter(user=request.user).latest('id')` this will return the last object he/she added (just you need a identifier which in this case is user). Or you can try this `YourModel.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-pk')[0]`

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, thank you, man.

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, man, but it returns en error like ```Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field```

Comment: Welcome buddy : )

Comment: see inside your model, user is your field(look at your model) in model which represents your authenticated user.

Comment: Or do one thing can you post your model in question ? I can reform the query

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, did it, man

Comment: Got it, in your model there should be a field for user too, as how you are gonna identify who has uploaded it ?  There should be a field for who has uploaded it (association with user). something like `user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)`

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, man, I did do it already, It's ```checked_by``` filter. Then, it means in your query instead of ```user``` I should write ```checked_by```, yeah ? I'm trying.

Comment: Is CurretUserField represents your User who uploaded it?

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, yes. And I've tried the method that I said. Returns again ```'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'checked_by'```

Comment: You have done all migrations right?. The it should work `OrginalDocument.objects(checked_by= request.user).latest('id')`, in that filter. If this didn't work then post your form too and that customuserfield code

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug, and now it returns **cking error ```'Manager' object is not callable```. This problem has really taken all my week and it means I just should terminate everything about this stuck project. BTW, man, ```CurrentUserField``` is a ```django-currentuser``` plugin which returns authenticated user. Thank you so much again. If I find solution, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Finding solution with the help of @k33da_lets_debug become so easy. I've changed query to this:

```
last_uploaded = OriginalDocument.objects.latest('id')
```

And that's all.